# Multi-step webform hooks

Tags: 8, hooks, webforms

I have built a multi-step webform which has some field on first page (checkboxes, selectboxes etc.). I tried to access `$form_state` on second page in **MYTHEME_form_alter** where is checked if `$form['progress']['#current_page'] == 'second_page'`.

When am I on second page I add custom element via $form variable

```
$form['custom'] = [
    'button_generate' => [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Download as PDF'),
        '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
        '#submit' => ['createPdfTemplate'],
    ]
];
```

this is how **createPdfTemplate** looks

```
function createPdfTemplate(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state)
{
    dd($form_state->getValues());
}
```

I'm trying to get data from $form_state from `'first_page'` and put them into twig template, but somehow in **createPdfTemplate** I can only access info about my button (i mean: $form['custom']['button_generate']) that called the action.

Anyone who could give me a hint what am i doing wrong, please.